# In Verilog, How is a 4:1 Mux made using case statements without creating a D-latch?

Tags: fpga, verilog, multiplexer, cases

Whenever I try to make a 4:1(32:8) mux in verilog using the following statement:

```
always@(*)begin  
case(sel)
    2'b00:Din1=Qsel;
    2'b01:Din1={Qsel[15:8],data[7:0]};
    2'b10:Din1={data[15:8],Qsel[7:0]};
    2'b11:Din1=data;
    default:Din1=Qsel;
endcase 
end
```

I get the error

```
[Place 30-574] Poor placement for routing between an IO pin and BUFG. If this sub optimal condition is acceptable for this design, you may use the CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE constraint in the .xdc file to demote this message to a WARNING. However, the use of this override is highly discouraged. These examples can be used directly in the .xdc file to override this clock rule.
< set_property CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE FALSE [get_nets sel_IBUF[0]] >

sel_IBUF[0]_inst (IBUF.O) is locked to IOB_X0Y34
 and sel_IBUF_BUFG[0]_inst (BUFG.I) is provisionally placed by clockplacer on BUFGCTRL_X0Y1
```

If I use if / else logic instead:

```
always@(*)begin 
    if(sel[1]&!sel[0])
        Din1<={data[15:8],Qsel[7:0]};
    else if(!sel[1]&sel[0])
        Din1<={Qsel[15:8],data[7:0]};
    else if(sel[1]&sel[0])
        Din1<=data;
    else
        Din1<=Qsel;
end
```

I don't get the problem anymore.

The RTL schematic looks like this:
[image: RTL Schematic]

It's creating a d-latch whenever the "select" inputs are asserted. I only want the value to be stored whenever my FPGA's clock ticks. Any solution to use case statements with combinatorial logic?

Comment: How is `sel` declared (is it more than 2 bits)? Which of your signals are connected to top level IO's (so we can figure out which signals might be sourced from an IBUF)?

Comment: Also, it looks like you really have two 2:1 muxes, one outputting `Din1[7:0]` and the other outputting `Din1[15:8]`. I'm not sure if this would help un-jam the synthesis tool.

Comment: @ThePhoton Sel is declared as two bits, and they're both connected to top level IO's, the problem seems to fix itself with if/else logic, but i can't understand why.

Comment: @ThePhoton Also, they should both be outputting the same amount of bits, if you're talking about the case statements, i'm concatenating two different inputs into one output

Comment: Your post does not make sens. The error message show has nothing whatsoever to do with your mux code producing latches or register. I very much suspect you have code outside what you show us which is the cause of your troubles.

Answer (score -1):

First, it doesn't make sense when you say you want to use to use the clock using combinatorial logic. Combinatorial logic has no memory but updating outputs only on the clock implies a type of memory being used since the output must be remembered between clock edges.

If you want your mux to follow the clock then it has to be using the clock for something.

You need to add a clock input to your mux, where every clock edge updates the mux output based on the input. As it is, your mux has no clock so it just operates whenever (whenever an input is changed) so it needs a D-latch.

Comment: @RonnieStevenson Clocks are special signals. They get their own dedicated (and limited) clock distribution network on the FPGA since it must go pretty much everywhere but also have minimal propagation delay and arrival jitter. It also  means you have to let your synthesizer know that a signal is a clock signal. I only know VHDL, not verilog, but in both their is a keyword like "edge" or "rising" or something like that which you use in a conditional statement that signifies to the software that the signal being acted on is a clock signal.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, I'm not trying to create a clock using combinatorial logic. I have an always on clock, where on every positive edge it should store the value at D, but for some reason a clock enable is being made which shouldn't be there since it was never defined it in the first place.

Comment: @RonnieStevenson Where is this clock signal for the muxes? I do not see it.

Comment: Does every mux need to have a clock signal? Can't they be treated like wires?

Comment: @RonnieStevenson You also seem new, so just a heads up for when you start connecting your FPGA inputs to things outside your FPGA, you will need to "synchronize" the input to your "clock domain: or you will get strange behaviour. You can look up what that is.

Comment: @RonnieStevenson Yes. FPGAs are close to a sea of gates but they have limitations. One of them is that unclocked circuits are very picky and finicky since they depend on propagation delays and timing which cannot be guaranteed in an FPGA since there are different lengths of routing connections everywhere. The logic blocks in an FPGA are not just wires like you might expect in a mux you built from discrete parts. You will need to manually read in each input on every clock cycle and manually place the output  to the appropriate state every clock cycle.

Comment: A mux in an FPGA is NOT just wires with switches to connect the wires differently. Pretty much everything in an FPGA runs through the logic block. It's something that has to read the inputs, run it through a lookup table or something similar and then produce an output, even if it's identical to the input.  It can't just pass it through on a wire. If you look at the logic block of an FPGA (varies between manufacturers but you'll get the idea) you will see it is not what you think it is.

Comment: So you're saying that a mux has to be told when to read those inputs, correct? and that "time" is based on an inputted clock signal?

Comment: A MUX is purely combinational logic. Full stop.